# How to break objects with flexbox and react correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a case where elements are grouped in rows, so that their heights are the same, when one element in the row resizes, but when screen gets smaller I want to flex elements in column, but changing their order somewhat. The problem is that I do not want to create separate react component just for this different layout. I have a drawing here: [image]

Comment: Consider using CSS columns, with a breakpoint determining `column-count`.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your outer div's style

```
   flexWrap: 'wrap'
```

Check [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) for more information on it

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure the flexboxes in your first image. It looks like you currently have 3 flexboxes, each one being a row containing two items.

I would first start by having a top-level flexbox containing all elements. In that top-level flexbox, create 2 flexbox columns (using `flex-direction: column`) each containing 3 elements. The first flexbox column would contain blocks 1, 3, 5 and the second would contain 2, 4, 6. On a large screen, the parent flexbox should put these two inner flexboxes side-by-side. Add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the parent flexbox and once the screen becomes too small, the parent flexbox will push the second column below the first.

If you would like to create a break point yourself, use a media query. Once the screen becomes smaller than your breakpoint, change the `flex-direction` property on the parent flexbox to `flex-direction: column`.